# What is the right way of getting rows from PostgreSQL database using Psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I'm trying to get the PostgreSQL database connection in the python flask app and I would like to get it return the rows so I can have a name-based access to columns. I've tried to do it in accordance with Psycopg2 documentation, but wasn't successful.

Here's the code:

```
def get_connection():        
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_USER, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictRow)
    return cur
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=dictrow#module-psycopg2.extras) it seems fine but I'm getting an error:

```
File "/app/app.py", line 34, in get_connection
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictRow)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The docs you link to don't show DictRow being used in this way at all.  Maybe you meant to use DictCursor, which the docs do show being used in this way.

Comment: I don't want to argue, but _"class psycopg2.extras.DictRow(cursor) - A row object that allow by-column-name access to data."_  sounded to me like the thing, that I wanted. However your suggestion was right and helped me, thank you.